# What is the <appname>.rb file in /lib typically used for in a Ruby project?

Tags: ruby, structure

In reference to this question: [Ideal ruby project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614309/ideal-ruby-project-structure) I noticed that appname.rb is in lib, and is top level.

I was reading through a little of the Rake source code on Github, and I noticed their project structure is pretty much the same. They have a top level 'rake.rb' file in /lib, but I'm not sure what it's there for.

In The Pickaxe (Programming Ruby 1.9), they show an example of structuring a small project, with pretty much the same directory structure above, but there is no mention of the usage of a top level .rb in /lib.

So, my question is: What exactly is this thing typically used for in a Ruby project?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm sure it is, but I'm relatively new to Ruby. I don't know that much Ruby-foo right now. ;)

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a really good question to me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually (and certainly in the example of rake) the `appname.rb` file is a shortcut to require a lot of other files. If you take a look at that file in the Rake project on GitHub, most of what it does is require files in the `lib/rake` directory and include modules as necessary. That file is what lets you `require 'rake'` without having to know what individual files rake needs.

Answer (score 4):

Building on [Emily's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567737/what-is-the-appname-rb-file-in-lib-typically-used-for-in-a-ruby-project/1567824#1567824):

Some projects do an `autoload` instead of a `require` in that file. The latter will actually load all of the classes, whereas the former will simply tell the class-loading system how to find them if you reference them without a `require` statement of your own.

So the pattern would look like:

```
# in foo_project/lib/foo.rb:
module Foo
  autoload :Bar, 'foo/bar'
  autoload :Baz, 'foo/baz'
end

# in foo_project/lib/foo/bar.rb:
module Foo
  class Bar
  ...
end

# in foo_project/lib/foo/baz.rb:
module Foo
  class Baz
  ...
end
```

Then, in your project, you can do the following:

```
require 'foo'
# note: no require 'foo/bar' or 'foo/baz'
my_bar = Foo::Bar.new
```

Comment: I've heard of, but never used, autoload. That's neat!