# How do I set up a basic Ruby project?

Tags: ruby, project-structure

I want to create a small Ruby project with 10 ~ 20 classes/files. I need some gems and I want to use RSpec as a test framework.

I might want to build a gem later on, but that is not certain.

Is there some how-to or guide that shows me how to set up the basic structure of my project?

Questions that I have are:

- Where do I put all my custom Errors/Exceptions?
- Are there some conventions out there for naming directories like lib, bin, src etc?
- Where do I put test data or documents?
- Where do I require all my files so I have access to them in my project?

I know I could do everything from scratch, but I would like some guidance. There are some good gems out there that I could copy, but I am not certain what I really need and what I can delete.

I looked at http://gembundler.com/, but it stops after setting up Bundler.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614309/ideal-ruby-project-structure

Answer (score 169, accepted):

To get a good start, you can use the `bundle gem` command and `rspec --init`.

```
~/code $ bundle gem my_lib
      create  my_lib/Gemfile
      create  my_lib/Rakefile
      create  my_lib/LICENSE.txt
      create  my_lib/README.md
      create  my_lib/.gitignore
      create  my_lib/my_lib.gemspec
      create  my_lib/lib/my_lib.rb
      create  my_lib/lib/my_lib/version.rb
Initializating git repo in /Users/john/code/my_lib
~/code $ cd my_lib/
~/code/my_lib $ git commit -m "Empty project"
~/code/my_lib $ rspec --init
The --configure option no longer needs any arguments, so true was ignored.
  create   spec/spec_helper.rb
  create   .rspec
```

- code goes in `lib`
- specs go in `spec`
- test data or documents go in `spec/fixtures/`
- Require all your ruby files in `lib/my_lib.rb`. You can define your exceptions in that file, too, or in their own files -- according to your own preference.
- C source files go in `ext/my_lib`
- shell scripts and executables go in `bin`

When in doubt, just look at how other gems are laid out.

---

*Further information:*

You should add rspec as a development dependency in your gemspec to make things easier for other developers

1. Edit my_lib.gemspec, adding `gem.add_development_dependency 'rspec'` and `gem.add_development_dependency 'rake'` near the bottom.
2. Add `Bundler.setup` and `require 'my_lib'` to the top of spec/spec_helper.rb to ensure your gem dependencies are loaded when you run your specs.
3. Add `require "rspec/core/rake_task"` and `task :default => :spec` to your Rakefile, so that running `rake` will run your specs.

While you're working on your newest creation, [guard-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec) can save you time and hassle by *automatically* running your specs as files change, alerting you to spec failures.

```
~/code/my_lib $ git add spec/spec_helper.rb
~/code/my_lib $ git commit -am "Add RSpec"
~/code/my_lib $ vim my_lib.gemspec # add guard development dependency
~/code/my_lib $ bundle
~/code/my_lib $ bundle exec guard init
~/code/my_lib $ vim Guardfile # Remove the sections below the top one
~/code/my_lib $ git add Guardfile
~/code/my_lib $ git commit -am "Add Guard"
```

After you're happy with your creation, push it up to github

```
# create a github repository for your gem, then push it up
~/code/my_lib $ curl -u myusername https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"my_lib"}' 
~/code/my_lib $ git remote add origin git@github.com:myusername/my_lib.git
~/code/my_lib $ git push
```

Then, when you're ready to release your gem on Rubygems.org, run `rake release`, which will walk you through the steps.

```
~/code/my_lib $ rake release
```

Further References

- The [Rubygems patterns guide](https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/) (and [home page](https://guides.rubygems.org)), from Matheus Moreira's answer. They're really great references
- [How I Start](https://howistart.org/posts/ruby/1/) by Steve Klabnik
- [Exercise 46: A Project Skeleton](https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex46.html) from Zed Shaw's [Learn Ruby The Hard Way](https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/)
- [New Gem with Bundler](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler) video on Railscasts
- [docs](https://bundler.io/v1.10/bundle_gem.html)

Comment: you can use `-b, [--bin=Generate a binary for your library.]` with `bundle gem`.

Comment: You can also use `bundle gem <gem-name> -t` to do the equivalent of `rspec --init` all at once.

Comment: How to execute the ruby project. I have built a console based ruby project for student teacher timetable. Not sure how to execute it??

Answer (score 11):

There are [some nice guides at rubygems.org](http://guides.rubygems.org/) that will introduce you to the conventions and the reasoning behind some of them. In general, the [Rubygems naming and directory conventions](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/) are followed by most Ruby developers.

I would only create custom exception classes if I wasn't able to find any class in the standard library fits the error description. Nest your error class under the class or module that raises it:

```
class Parser::Error < RuntimeError; end

begin
  Parser.new(:invalid).parse!
rescue Parser::Error => e
  puts e.message
end
```

Unit tests go either into `/test`, if you're using [`Test::Unit`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Unit_testing), or into `/spec` if you're using [`RSpec`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec). I recommend the latter.

[`Bundler`](http://gembundler.com/) is a great way to manage your load path. It will automatically set up your environment with only the dependencies specified on the `Gemfile` and optionally the `gemspec`. It also allows you to easily `require` your code without making it a gem.

However, since you might bundle your code in a gem in the future, I recommend investigating [how to create gem specifications](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#first-gem). You should write your specification manually. Don't use some tool to automagically generate it - they are, in my opinion, brute force approaches that needlessly duplicate information and wreak havoc when used with source control.

[I created a gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rookie) which you may find useful. Given a `gemspec` file, it defines many useful `Rake` tasks for working with your gem, which include tasks for building, installing and releasing your gem to `rubygems` and `git` repository with automatic version tagging. It also provides an easy way to load your code in a `irb` or `pry` session.

```
# Rakefile
require 'rookie'

# Run `rake -T` for the complete task list
Rookie::Tasks.new('your_gem.gemspec').define_tasks!
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are the conventions I have most often seen (assuming your project's name is "foo"):

- /lib/foo.rb - Defines the top-level namespace of the project and its version; requires needed files.
- /lib/foo/ - Contains all classes for your project, including error-related classes.
- /test/ - Contains tests for your project.
- /spec/ - Contains the specs for your project.
- /bin/ - If your project depends on binaries (JAR files, etc.), they usually go in there.

Inside lib/, the convention is usually to create a folder for each sub-namespace inside your top-level namespace. For example, the class Foo::Bar::Baz is usually found under /lib/foo/bar/baz.rb.

Some people like to create a /lib/foo/version.rb file just to set the Foo::VERSION constant, but very often I have seen this defined in the /lib/foo.rb file.

Also, if you are creating a gem, you will need the following files:

- /Rakefile - Defines rake tasks (such as tasks for testing, building and pushing the gem).
- /Gemfile - Defines the source of the gem (among other possible things).
- /foo.gemspec - Describes your gem and provides a list of dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

There're some guides on the internet about how to structure a Ruby project. Besides, I think the best way to solve this is heading over github and looking for some famous Ruby project, and check "their" structures.

Besides general ruby gem requirements, I recommend the following tools for better workflow:

- [editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) , helps developers define and maintain consistent coding styles between different editors and IDEs.
- [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) , static code analyzer for ruby, the defac to linter in ruby community.
- [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) , together with a bunch of plugins, you can run any commands as you like when code changes, automatically.
- [rake](https://github.com/ruby/rake) , the universal driver for various project tasks, such as:

  - `package`: build gem package
  - `clean`: clean generated files
  - `test`: run test
- [yard](http://yardoc.org/) , popular ruby documentation tool.

And besides all of the above tools, their're some online service for ruby project:

- CI(Continuous Integration)

  - [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/)
  - [circleci](https://circleci.com/)
  - [codeship](https://codeship.com/)
- Code Review

  - [codeclimate](https://codeclimate.com/)

And you can even genearate badges via http://shields.io/ for your open source project.

That's my experience, hope it helps for some one.